# what is this format for seconds XXXXXXX.XXXXX:XXX (Win32_NetworkLoginProfile)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Querying a WMi object on the

```
$colItems = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkLoginProfile -Namespace "root\CIMV2" 
                  | Where-Object {$_.name -match "Name"} | Select-Object name,PasswordAge
```

according to MSDN

> PasswordAge
>
> Data type: datetime
> Access type: Read-only
> Length of time a password has been in effect. This value is measured from the number of seconds elapsed since the password was last changed.
> Example: 00001201000230.000000 000

I am getting

```
00000068235223.000000:000
```

So I have tried casting this to `TimeSpan`and `DateTime` no luck.
what does the colon represent how to get number hours it represent.

---

Thanks Adding the WMI class name to title for the next poor soul that get confused by documentation wording.

---

here is what works

That worked perfectly                                                                            $str = "00000068235223.000000:000"
$ts = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToTimeSpan($str)

Days              : 68
Hours             : 23
Minutes           : 52
Seconds           : 23
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 59611430000000
TotalDays         : 68.9947106481481
TotalHours        : 1655.87305555556
TotalMinutes      : 99352.3833333333
TotalSeconds      : 5961143
TotalMilliseconds : 5961143000

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a long datetime string to days in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352308/how-to-convert-a-long-datetime-string-to-days-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The actual format of `PasswordAge` is `"ddddddddHHmmss.ffffff:000"` that is, 8 digits of days, then 2 digits of hours, then minutes, then seconds, then fractions. They say use `[TimeSpan]::ParseExact($string,"ddddddddHHmmss.ffffff:000",$null)` but I can't make it work in my PS4/Win7. Really weird.

Comment: @Vesper: see my comment below.

Answer (score 5):

This is the DMTF time interval format which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390895(v=vs.85).aspx). Basically it is string that encodes a time span in the form `ddddddddHHMMSS.mmmmmm:000`. Note that for time intervals, the ending is always `:000`.

From the docs:

> The following example shows the format of a date-time interval.
>   ddddddddHHMMSS.mmmmmm:000
>   The following table lists the fields of the date-time interval.
>   Field   Description
>   dddddddd    Eight digits that represent a number of days (00000000 through 99999999).
>   HH  Two-digit hour of the day that uses the 24-hour clock (00 through 23).
>   MM  Two-digit minute in the hour (00 through 59).
>   SS  Two-digit number of seconds in the minute (00 through 59).
>   mmmmmm  Six-digit number of microseconds in the second (000000 through 999999).

I believe the documentation is somewhat misleading for this field, since it is implying the whole numbers are full seconds, but in fact it is a string format representing days, hours, minutes, seconds, etc.

You should use `[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToTimeSpan` to convert this string to a .NET Timespan, however, for whatever reason I actually received an array instead of a string for PasswordAge, so I had to use this:

```
$p = gwmi Win32_NetworkLoginProfile
[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToTimeSpan($p.PasswordAge[1])
```

Comment: I think it is just poorly worded - saying it is _measured from the number of seconds_ not that it is the number of seconds. It is misleading about the datetime format rather than time interval.

Comment: The main trouble that `[TimeSpan]::ParseExact($string,"ddddddddHHmmss.ffffff:000",$null)` does not produce a valid timespan with any of the supplied strings, while the docs say it should.

Comment: @Vesper : See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719055/why-does-timespan-parseexact-not-work. The correct format string should be @"ddddddddhhmmss\.ffffff\:\0\0\0" (note hh not HH & escaping of ALL values that are not defined specifiers for time interval)

Answer (score 4):

To add to all the previous answers, the proper routine to make something out of this type of strings is call [`[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToTimeSpan($string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter.totimespan.aspx). This will produce a `[System.TimeSpan]` object, which you can then parse in a better way.

Credit for class to do conversion goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4320670/1627055).

Comment: I would have mentioned this in my answer, however my attempts always received an error saying that the value "out of range of valid values".

Comment: That worked perfectly                                                                            $str = "00000068235223.000000:000"
$ts = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToTimeSpan($str)
$ts
12


Days              : 68
Hours             : 23
Minutes           : 52
Seconds           : 23
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 59611430000000
TotalDays         : 68.9947106481481
TotalHours        : 1655.87305555556
TotalMinutes      : 99352.3833333333
TotalSeconds      : 5961143
TotalMilliseconds : 5961143000

Comment: Ok for some reason `PasswordAge` is an array for me, not sure why, but this works.

Answer (score 1):

Those are [`CIM_DATETIME` values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx) or [Interval values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390895(v=vs.85).aspx).  The format is defined by the CIM standard that WMI is built upon.

With normal datetime values, the WMI object provides a converter function.  For example:

```
$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.PasswordExpires);
```

But that doesn't work for intervals, which is what `PasswordAge` is.

The MS doc you point to says the value is the number of seconds, but I believe that means **the precision is to the second**, not that the value is literally **in seconds**.  My current password says it's 43 years old if that were the case, for example, and that's not possible.  So it must use the Interval format.

I would do this:

```
$PasswordAge = New-TimeSpan -Days $_.PasswordAge.Substring(0,8) `
    -Hours $_.PasswordAge.Substring(8,2) `
    -Minutes $_.PasswordAge.Substring(10,2) `
    -Seconds $_.PasswordAge.Substring(12,2);
```

Remember to use `$PasswordAge.TotalHours` and not just `$PasswordAge.Hours` if you want the actual age value expressed in hours and not just the hour value of the timespan.

Edit:  @Vesper is right.  You can just use:

```
[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToTimeSpan($_.PasswordAge);
```